# JOIN table and show row with closest upcoming date

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I show the **closest upcoming event** in a row?

Let's say I have two tables:

```
EVENTS
|id |venueID    |eventName   |date        |
|---|-----------|------------|------------|
|10 |1          |Volleyball  |2018-08-01  |
|11 |1          |Concert     |2018-08-05  |
|12 |1          |Faire       |2018-08-07  |


VENUES
|id |Name       |
|---|-----------|
|1  |Place1     |
|2  |Place2     |
```

Since today is Aug 3, the upcoming event would be "Concert" and the table would look like this:

```
|Venue    |Event   |Date       |
|---------|--------|-----------|
|Place1   |Concert |2018-08-05 |
```

The current code I have has the problem that if there are multiple upcoming events, then the **whole row is duplicated** as many times as there are events.

I would like each row with a Venue to be shown only once, with only the closest upcoming event.

Also, I would like to have the row with the venue shown even if there are **no upcoming events**. Instead, it could say something like "No Upcoming Events".

Here's what I have

```
SELECT
venues.id,
venues.Name,
events.eventName,
events.date

FROM VENUES

JOIN EVENTS
     ON (venues.id = events.venueID)

WHERE events.date >= '$current_date'
```

Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `apply` :

```
select v.Venue, coalesce(e.Event, 'No Upcoming Events') Event, e.Date 
from VENUES v outer apply
     ( select top (1) e.*
       from event e
       where e.venueID = v.id and
             e.date >= '$current_date'
       order by e.date
     ) e;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative to using `APPLY` (which is probably the better approach). After comparing the query plan of this against an answer using `OUTER APPLY`, I'd have to say *this is the inferior approach*.  There may be some good reason to use a window function - a more complicated scenario perhaps.

This uses a window function to get row numbers by a sort criteria, in this case the date.  The result is joined to the list of venues with only the 1 row returned (the one with the earliest date).  If two events have the same venue and same date, only one will get the row number of 1.  You can not use window functions in APPLY, hence the inner query.

```
SELECT v.Name Venue
   , COALESCE(eRanked.eventName, 'No Events') Event
   , eRanked.Date
FROM Venues v
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT e.VenueId, e.eventName, e.date
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.VenueId ORDER BY e.Date) rowId
    FROM Events e
    WHERE e.date > '$curent_date'
) eRanked ON eRanked.VenueId = v.id AND eRanked.RowId = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use `apply`:

```
SELECT v.id, v.Name, e.eventName, e.date
FROM VENUES v CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) e.*
      FROM EVENTS e
      WHERE v.id = e.venueID AND e.date >= '$current_date'
     ) e;
```

If you wanted to include venues that had no upcoming events, you would use `OUTER APPLY` instead of `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: Hey @Gordon, it seems you have forgotten to place a `top(1)` in your subquery. As it stands the query will list *all* future events for a given list of venues, see here http://rextester.com/ZRQTKU37112

Comment: @cars10m . . . Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *good old fashioned* solution that will work without `cross apply`:

```
select vid, place,eventName,date 
from venues 
left join
  (select evid nevid, min(date) ndate from events where date>getdate()
   group by evid) nxtevents ON nevid=vid
left join events ON evid=vid AND date=ndate
```

It uses two `left joins` instead and relies on the condition that there will not be two events on the same day in the same venue ...

See a demo here: http://rextester.com/RDAPR97793